# Retrieving two COUNTs using a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Assume Table1 has c1 column for which allowed values are either 1 or 0.

How to retrieve number of 0s, 1s with a single query? Is it possible?

sorry, STUPID way of questioning.

I wanted the answer in a single row, not single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a single table/index read. Subqueries will most likely have two such reads

```
SELECT
   COUNT(CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Ones,
   COUNT(CASE status WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Zeros
FROM
   MyTable
```

..and it's portable too

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, just `GROUP BY` that column.

```
SELECT c1, count(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY c1;
```

Comment: I'll downvote because this does not count ones and zeros separately.: it does not answer the question

Comment: The question was clarified after I've submitted my reply - can't change that! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate way;

```
select
   sum(c1) as ones, 
   count(*) - sum(c1) as zeros
from
   Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the DBMS you're using.
In oracle the following is possible:

```
select
 (select count(status) from table1 where status = 0) as status_0,
 (select count(status) from table1 where status = 1) as status_1
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Already been answered, but there's always (nearly) more than one way to do it. Union of two queries?

```
select count(*) from t1 where value='0' 
union
select count(*) from t1 where value='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

> select uid from emp
>
> UID 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0

```
select distinct

(select count(uid) from emp  where uid = 0) zeros_total,

(select count(uid) from emp where uid = 1) ones_total

from 
emp
```

**O/P**
**zeros_total 5 ones_total 4**